# count number of files in windows 7 search without duplicate ones

Tags: windows-7, vbscript

I scanned some files in my office in the pdf format and renamed the files and pasted them in different folders. In some cases I pasted the same files with the same names in 2 or more different folders. Now when I do a search with the search term "pdf" in the parent folder (parent folder contains all the subfolders which contain only the scanned pdf files) I get around 2000 files as the count. Now I know this search also includes the duplicate files which I pasted. So how do I get a count of all the scanned files without any duplicates? Can I use any scripts from the command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for only the solution, try easyduplicate finder or similar software, it will be easy.

if you want script information, please post what u have in hand as script to start with...

there isnt a simple command in cmd window you could type to search this..